# Xamarin Forms FlyoutPage on landscape tablet

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, flyout

I am running the latest Xamarin Forms on VS 2019 community edition.
I just started the basic Xamarin Forms project and added a Flyout page template to it.
When running this on the Android emulator it works fine, but the menu won't close after selecting a page.
The code has not changed apart from adding another page to the menu items.
[image]

The code `isPresented = false` is still there but has no effect whatsover.
Is it simply not possible to have the menu collapse in landscape mode? Then what are my alternatives?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `isPresented = false`, is the breakpoint reached?  Note that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage#navigation-behavior says "On Android, the detail and flyout pages are overlaid on each other."  I'm not sure whether that means the flyout is there, but is supposed to hide behind the detail page. If you make the detail page a bit taller, do the flyout menu items still show, but moved farther down the screen? Or does the taller detail page hide some of the menu items?

Comment: Yes it reaches that point. That code is in the same scope as the code that changs out the page. The menu does not get removed and is not in front of the page and is actually seperate. I think this is expected behavious but want to turn it off basically.

Comment: According to the doc, it isn't expected behavior. "Overlaid" means occupying the same space on the screen. Post xaml for page containing the menu.

Comment: It is just the flyout template. If you want to test it, it is easier to do so by making a new solution and adding a flyout and then starting that on a tablet in landscape.

Comment: @Gertjan Brouwer I find the [same problem](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13852) at github, it is not resolved, you can follow up.

Comment: Yeh the last comment is based on my question. It won't get solved since Xamarin.forms is deprecated and will be replaced in november this year.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer Please be patient and wait for the latest version.

Comment: There won't be another version of Xamarin. I already made the whole thing custom

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer hoe heb jij dit opgelost? Heb namelijk ook dit probleem nu

Comment: @AbusiveVids I made a static view model. This has a bool IsPresented and a Command which will receive a MenuOption(custom). This command will set IsPresented = !IsPresented and set the App.MainPage to the type of page in my MenuOption. MenuOption is a class which contains a bool indicating if this option is selected, which icon it should have, which text and which page it should go to. A List of MenuOption in the static view model is referenced in a contentview to show these options. The menu content view is used where needed and I add a data trigger to it.

Comment: This data trigger checks for the IsPresented. If it changes it will call a helper function which will use a transition to remove the menu to the left. I have a lot more stuff connected to it but this is the gist of it.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer do you maybe have an example on Git?

Comment: There is no fix, it is custom made

Comment: Can you share the code of your custom made?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add in the `MenuPage` (the main file, the first one that is generated) the following property:

```
FlyoutLayoutBehavior = "Popover"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MasterMenuItem ()
{
InitializeComponent ();
MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover; // This solve my problem
}
```